# Set class styles to items in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to put a underline in my nav list with this code.

```
 const [classOn, setClassOn] = useState('menu_selected');
    const [linkMenu, setLinkMenu] = useState('');

    function handleSelectedMenu(nb){
        setLinkMenu(document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li'));
        for(let i=1; i<linkMenu.length; i++){
            linkMenu[i].firstChild.classList.remove(classOn)
        } 
        linkMenu[nb].firstChild.classList.add(classOn) 
    }
```

on full screen, nothing happens and I get an error in my console log

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstChild')
```

but when I open mobile viewer, the styles are been applied.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class name directly on the element based on an existing state, like:

```
function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

function FakeElement = () => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li
      className={classNames(
        hidden
          ? "hidden-class"
          : "",
        "default-class other-default-class"
      )}
    >Stuff</li>
  );
}
```

U can add a lot of conditions in classNames function.

Comment: I solve the problem using ```styles.menu_selected```.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this.

```
<ul onMouseOver={() => setLinkMenu(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setLinkMenu(false)}
      className={`${linkMenu ? 'block ' : 'hidden '}`} >
       {options.map((option) => (
         <li className="text-sm p-2 block w-full"
        key={option}
        onClick={() => setLinkMenu(false)}>{option}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I solve the problem using ```styles.menu_selected```.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using `styles.menu_selected`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).